# Android OpenGL ES 2, Drawing squares

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

***EDIT: Problem solved!***
So I've been going through the official OpenGL ES 2 tutorials for Android, and I've gotten to the part that involves drawing shapes, but I can't seem to get a square to work. It draws a right triangle instead.

I've included the code that I'm using to define and draw the shape, which is copied almost exactly from the tutorial. The Renderer class simply creates an instance of this shape and calls the draw method.

For some reason, the tutorial does not give the values/declaration for vertexStride and vertexCount, so the ones I have in there are educated guesses. I've tried several values for vertexCount (1 thru 12), and none work.

Thanks in advance.

```
            public class Square {

                private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
                private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

                // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
                static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
                static float squareCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

                private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
                float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };


                private final String vertexShaderCode =
                        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                        "void main() {" +
                        "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                        "}";

                private final String fragmentShaderCode =
                    "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

                int mProgram;

                static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
                static final int vertexCount = 4;

                public Square() {
                    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4); // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
                    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
                    vertexBuffer.position(0);

                    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
                    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2); // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
                    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
                    drawListBuffer.position(0);


                    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
                    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

                    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
                    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
                    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
                    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
                }

                public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

                    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
                    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
                    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

                    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
                    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
                    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

                    return shader;
                }

                public void draw() {
                    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
                    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

                    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
                    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

                    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
                    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

                    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
                    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

                    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
                    int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

                    // Set color for drawing the triangle
                    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

                    // Draw the triangle
                    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

                    // Disable vertex array
                    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actually, I found that just using GL_TRANGLE_FAN in place of GL_TRIANGLES as an argument for glDrawArrays() resolves the issue. Problem solved!

Although if anybody could point me towards an API that actually explains all the methods and values instead of just listing them like Android's does, that'd be great.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124636/gldrawarrays-vs-gldrawelements

Answer (score 28):

```
vertexCount = squareCoords.length/COORDS_PER_VERTEX; //Vertex count is the array divided by the size of the vertex ex. (x,y) or (x,y,z) 
vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;                //4 are how many bytes in a float
```

Let me know if that worked out for you, good luck.

I think your also missing the `ModelViewProjection` Matrix used to convert 3D space to 2D screen space. mvpMatrix should be passed in by the draw function `draw(float[] mvpMatrix)`
Forgot to mention you also should use `DrawElements(...)` (used in example) if you do there's no need for the count or stride, just the length of an idicies array and a drawing buffer.

```
    // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                          GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

Comment: I think this answer deserves a green check-mark. Partly because it clearly explains the `vertexCount` and `vertexStride` questions but also because it points to the `GLES20.glDrawElements(...)` function (which in this case should replace the `GLES20.glDrawArray(...)` function). The `ModelViewProjection` isn't required, as of my experience, unless you don't transform your world coordinates before drawing your square (which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: @dbm Thanks! I tried to keep it short and simple so I might have missed something any other critiques? I used the ModelViewProjection mainly because thats what I use, but also because I've changed my way of transforming the world coordinates before drawing.

Comment: Also seems to be missing mMVPMatrix from the vertexShaderCode ("uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +)

Answer (score 25):

The tutorial is missing some steps: [the final code for the square is here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/OpenGL/HelloOpenGLES20/src/com/example/android/opengl/Square.java).

The example was intended to use `glDrawElements` instead of `glDrawArrays` which is indicated by the presence of the line: `private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices`.

This array specifies the desired vertices of 2 triangles. 0, 1 and 2 for the first. Then 0, 2 and 3 for the second. `GL_TRANGLE_FAN` just happens to work because it will draw the next triangle using the first vertex in the buffer, the last vertex used in previous triangle and the next vertex. For the second triangle this is 0, 2 and 3. Then 0, 3 and 4, etc. Had vertex 2 been 5, 5 and vertex 3 been -5, 5, the resulting fan would not have been a square.

Replace these lines:

```
// Draw the triangle
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
```

With these:

```
// Draw the square
GLES20.glDrawElements(
    GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Jon W
I think the difference between GL_TRIANGLES & GL_TRIANGLE_FAN is explained in the picture:

http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.naturewizard.com/Tutorials/Tutorial01/images/image009.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.naturewizard.com/tutorial0104.html&h=719&w=604&sz=55&tbnid=15KBWSk5xZO7YM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=76&zoom=1&usg=__o554PpZhRv8TM8JTmLC9FpU7_ko=&docid=ELETRFsqMmNrvM&sa=X&ei=F0hnUcK9BMPA0QWn2oDABw&ved=0CEIQ9QEwAQ&dur=255

Comment: It be great if you explained how this answers the question