# Why is this glDrawElements call failing?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl

I am trying to integrate the advice from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10727/fastest-way-to-draw-quads-in-opengl-es and [How to draw with Vertex Array Objects and glDrawElements in PyOpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365484/how-to-draw-with-vertex-array-objects-and-gldrawelements-in-pyopengl) to render quads using an index buffer implemented by `OpenGL.arrays.vbo.VBO`, in a context provided by GLFW and using the helper class. (I am also, at least for now, relying on `ctypes` for raw data rather than using Numpy.)

I produced the following minimal example (if I can fix this, I should be able to fix the actual code):

```
import ctypes
import glfw
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders


def setup_window():
    glfw.init()
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
    window = glfw.create_window(256,256,'test',None,None)
    glfw.make_context_current(window)
    glfw.set_input_mode(window, glfw.STICKY_KEYS, True)
    return window


def get_program():
    VERTEX_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""
    #version 330
    layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
    }
    """, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    FRAGMENT_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""
    #version 330
    out vec4 outputColor;
    void main()
    {
        outputColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    """, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    return shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER)


window = setup_window()
glUseProgram(get_program())
vertices = vbo.VBO(
    (ctypes.c_float * 16)(
        -1, -1, 0, 0,
        -1, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 0,
        1, -1, 0, 0
    )
)
indices = vbo.VBO(
    (ctypes.c_float * 6)(
        0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3
    ),
    target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
)


while (
    glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) != glfw.PRESS
    and not glfw.window_should_close(window)
):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    with vertices, indices:
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()
```

The `glDrawElements` call fails with an entirely unhelpful "invalid operation" exception. When commented out, everything else seems to work fine (except that of course nothing is drawn).

What exactly is wrong here? I had understood that using the `VBO` instances as context managers (the `with` block) should ensure that the data is bound and thus should be available for `glDrawElements` to render.

I have also tried the following, to no effect:

- using explicit `.bind()` calls on the VBOs rather than the `with` block
- using empty data
- changing the `size` argument in the `glDrawElements` call to every other number I could imagine being right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a core profile [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context):

> ```py
> glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
> ```

In a core profile context you have to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default VAO (0) is not valid.
Either switch to a compatibility profile (`glfw.OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`) or create a Vertex Array Object. I recommend to create an VAO.

Anyway the buffers have to be bound after the VAO has been bound:

```py
indices.bind()
vertices.bind()
```

And the type of the indices has to be integral and the type which is specified at `glDrawElements` has to correspond to this type. For instance `c_int16` and `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`:

```py
indices = vbo.VBO(
    (ctypes.c_int16 * 6)(
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
    ),
    target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
)
```

Note the [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) is stated in the VAO, thus the VAO has to be bound before the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound.
[`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) associates, the currently bound `ARRAY_BUFFER`, to the specified attribute index in the currently bound VAO. THus the VAO and the [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) have to be bound before.

Example:

```py
window = setup_window()
program = get_program()
glUseProgram(program)

vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

vertices = vbo.VBO(
    (ctypes.c_float * 16)(
        -1, -1, 0, 1,
        -1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, -1, 0, 1
    )
)
indices = vbo.VBO(
    (ctypes.c_int16 * 6)(
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
    ),
    target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
)

indices.bind()
vertices.bind()
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

while (
    glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) != glfw.PRESS
    and not glfw.window_should_close(window)
):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()
```

Comment: That resolves the exception, but I still have no output (like the other StackOverflow poster initially complained about). I expect the window to be filled with green, since the triangles cover the entire coordinate space and the colour is specified in the fragment shader.

Comment: Any other ideas, then? I copied and pasted below the original `setup_window` and `get_program` definitions and still just have a black window. And I was successfully drawing stuff with other approaches (not involving an index buffer) before. :/

Comment: I tried the other approach of just changing `glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` to `glfw.OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE` and that *also* doesn't give me any rendered output.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The indices have to be 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3

Comment: AHA! That's it (setting W coords to 1) - and I had a problem like the before, actually. In the actual code, I will be using the ZW coords for texture and have them set properly by the shader. And I had the correct index values and type for the index array the first time, but messed up when I was producing the SSCCE. Egg on my face! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the results from the discussion, and my testing:

- The VBO class works fine; the `with` block works fine.
- A VAO must be created to work in the OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE. I had been confused as to how to make VAOs work with index buffers, but it turns out there isn't particularly anything to it - just set up the VAO and the rest of the code is the same. It can be as simple as `vao = glGenVertexArrays(1); glBindVertexArray(vao)`. This needs to happen before any function that needs the VAO; in this code, that essentially means "before the `with` block is entered". But of course, I also want it outside the `while` loop, since there is no point in re-creating it constantly (and I would also have to clean it up).
- I had messed up in several places in producing the data for the SSCCE. The index buffer needs to have data of `ctypes.c_int16` type (which it had originally); the actual indices in the buffer were wrong (again, I had them correct originally, following the gamedev.stackexchange example); and the W coordinates of the vertices need to be `1.0` rather than `0.0` (in my actual code base, the Z and W components are filled in by the shader, since I'm trying to do exclusively 2D rendering, and the vertex data will use those values for texture coordinates).