# PyOpenGL weird random colored triangles

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I wrote a simple program using PyOpenGL, to load a model then display it. But when I see the model, I also see a lot of random coloured triangle around it[image: Screenshoot]
I don't know, why does they appear, but I don't want them. Code:
prim.py(A primitive & a model class)

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from OpenGL.GL import *
from array import array


class Primitive():
  def __init__(self,vert,colors,colors2,drawMode,ind,x=0,y=0,z=0,s=0,rX=0,rY=0,rZ=0):
    #Csúcstömbadatok tárolása/Storing vertex-data
    self.vert=array('f',list(vert))
    #Színtömbadatok/Storing color-data
    self.colors=array('f',list(colors))
    #Indexadatok/Incidies
    self.ind=array('B',list(ind))
    #X-y eltolás/X-Y translation
    self.x,self.y,self.z=x,y,z
    #Elforgatás/Rotation
    self.rX,self.rY,self.rZ=rX,rY,rZ
    #Másodlagos színtömbadatok(Inaktív 3szög esetén)/Secondary coloring, when triangle is inactive
    self.colors2=array('f',list(colors2))
    #Aktív-inaktív/Active-inactive
    self.selected=s
    self.drawM=drawMode
  def draw(self):
    #Ideiglenes projekciós mártix létrehozása/Creating a temporary projection matrix
    glPushMatrix()
    #Döntés elsődlege-másodlagos szinezés között/Chosing betveen primary and secondary coloring
    if self.selected: glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colors.tostring( ) );cl=len(self.colors)/3
    else: glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colors2.tostring( ) );cl=len(self.colors2)/3
    #Csúcstömbadatok feltöltése/Uploading vertexarray
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vert.tostring( ) )
    #Eltolás/translation
    glTranslate(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    #Elforgatás/Rotation
    glRotate(self.rX,1,0,0)
    glRotate(self.rY,0,1,0)
    glRotate(self.rZ,0,0,1)
    #Kirajzolás/Drawing
    glDrawElements( self.drawM, len(self.vert)+cl, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.ind.tostring( ) )
    #Eredeti projekciós mátrix visszaállítása/Restoring original projection matrix
    glPopMatrix()

#Osztály tárolásra/A Class for storing
class ElementsList():
  def __init__(self,elements):
    #Elemeket egy listában tároljuk/We store the elements in a list
    self.el=list(elements)
  def __len__(self):
    #Elemszám/lenght
    return len(self.el)
  def __setitem__(self,key,value):
    #Elemek elérése/Access elements
    self.el[key]=value
  def __getitem__(self,key):
    #Elemek elérése/Access elements
    return self.el[key]
  def append(self,value):
    #Elemek elérése/Access elements
    self.el.append(value)
  def select(self,i):
    #Adott elem kiválasztása/Select an element
    for item in self.el: item.selected=0 #Összes elem kiválasztásának törlése/Deselect all elements
    self.el[i].selected=1 #Adott elem kiválasztása/Select element
  def draw(self): #Kirayzolás/Drawing
    for i in self.el: i.draw()
  def aCoords(self,x,y,z=0): #Aktív elem eltolása
    for i in self.el:    #\
      if i.selected==1:  # > Aktív elem kiválasztása/Select active element
        i.x+=x #Eltolás
        i.y+=y #Translation
        i.z+=z
  def Coords(self,x,y,z=0): #Összes elem eltolása/Translate all elements
    for i in self.el: #Minden elemre/For all elements
      i.x+=x
      i.y+=y
      i.z+=z
  def aRotate(self,rX,rY,rZ): #Aktív elem elforgatása/Rotate active element
    for i in self.el:
      if i.selected==1:
        i.rX+=rX
        i.rY+=rY
        i.rZ+=rZ
  def Rotate(self,rX,rY,rZ): #Összes elem elforgatása/Rotate all elements
    for i in self.el:
        i.rX+=rX
        i.rY+=rY
        i.rZ+=rZ


cVertices = [ -1,-1,1,
             -1,1,1,
             1,1,1,
             1,-1,1,
             -1,-1,-1,
             -1,1,-1,
             1,1,-1,
             1,-1,-1 ]

cColors = [ 0, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 0,
           1, 1, 0,
           0, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1,
           1, 0, 1,
           1, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 1]

cFaces = [0, 3, 2, 1,
          2, 3, 7, 6,
          0, 4, 7, 3,
          1, 2, 6, 5,
          4, 5, 6, 7,
          0, 1, 5, 4 ]
```

model.py(A simple slope model)

```python
from prim import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
vert=[1,1,1,
      2,1,1,
      1,1,2,
      2,1,2,
      1,2,1,
      2,2,1]
colors=[1,1,1,
        1,0,1,
        0,1,1,
        1,1,0,
        1,0,0,
        0,0,1
        ]
faces=[0,1,5,4,
       0,1,3,2,
       3,2,4,5]
faces2=[0,2,4,
        1,5,3]
m1=Primitive(vert,colors,colors,GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,faces)
m2=Primitive(vert,colors,colors,GL_TRIANGLES,faces2)
model=ElementsList([m1,m2])
```

modelview.py(The main program)

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Importálások/Importing
import pygame # a pygame "játékmodul"/pygame "gamemodule"
from OpenGL.GL import * #OpenGL grafika/OpenGL graphics
from ctypes import * #C-kompatibilis elemek(pl. c_int)/C-compat. elements(for ex. c_int)
from array import array #powerful array class
from prim import *
from model import model
print("Modules imported")
#Inicializáció/initializing
pygame.init ()
#Ablak létrehozása/Creating a window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((1000,1200), pygame.OPENGL|pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 24)
#OpenGL nézetport beállítása/Set OpenGL's viewport
glViewport (0, 0, 1000, 1200)
glOrtho( -8, 8, -8, 8, -8, 8 )
#Törlőszín/Clear Color
glClearColor (0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
#Csúcs-és színtömbök engedélyezése
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY )
#Mélységtesz engedélyezése/Enable Depth Test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
#Simítás/Smoothing
glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH )
#Rotáció/Rotation
rX,rY,rZ=0,0,0
#'Futási indikátor'/Flag for running
done=0
#Eseménykezelő fügvények/Event handling functions
def rightFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(10,0,0)
def leftFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(-10,0,0)
def upFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(0,10,0)
def downFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(0,-10,0)
def plusFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(0,0,10)
def minusFunction(): global model; model.Rotate(0,0,-10)
def qFunction(): global done; done=1 #Kilépési 'zászló'/Exiting 'flag'
print("Functions created")
#Eseménykezelő szótár, nagyjából a C++-s switch utasítás/Event handling dictionary, like the switch in C++
eventHandler={
    pygame.K_UP:upFunction, #K_xx egy konstans, egy szám
    pygame.K_DOWN:downFunction, #K_xx is a constant value(a number)
    pygame.K_LEFT:leftFunction,
    pygame.K_RIGHT:rightFunction,
    pygame.K_q:qFunction,
    pygame.K_KP_PLUS:plusFunction,
    pygame.K_KP_MINUS:minusFunction
    }
print("Events bound")
#Örökciklus/Infinite loop
while not done:
  #For-each ciklus az eseményeken
  #For-each loop in the events
  for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Ha kilép, akkor a ciklusból is
        #If clicked the X, exit from the loop
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=1
        #Hívás az eseménykezelő szótárra
        #Calling the event handler dictionary
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #try:
              eventHandler[event.key]()
            #except: print("Unbound key")
  #Törlés/Clear the screen
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )
  #Kirajzolófügvények/Drawing functions
  model.draw()
  #Kép frissítése/Updating
  pygame.display.flip()
#Cikluson kívül/Outside of the loop
print("Program finished!")
#Kilépés/quit
pygame.quit()
```

You can see the result above.
How can I fix this error?

**Edit:**
If I replace the **model.py* file with this:

```python
from prim import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
model=Primitive(cVertices,cColors,cColors,GL_QUADS,cFaces) #To draw a cube
```

then it works fine. I think the problem is around the VBO's data.

**EDIT:**
If I replace the **model.py** file with this:

```python
from prim import Primitive
from OpenGL.GL import *
vert=[0,0,0,
      1,0,0,
      0,1,0,
      1,1,0]
face=[0,1,3,2]
colors=[1,1,1, #That isn't changed
        1,0,1,
        0,1,1,
        1,1,0,
        1,0,0,
        0,0,1
        ]
model=Primitive(vert,colors,colors,GL_QUADS,face)
```

Then there aren't any weird primitives. BUT when I try to use the "old" **vert** list, there are some quads appear.
I wrote a simple program for thesting the Primitive class, It works fine in 2D, & 3D(With the cube)

Comment: I read in another question about PyOpenGL that there are problems with VBO bindings in PyOpenGL that cause "weird bugs". I'm no expert on PyOpenGL so I can't really say if that's an issue here or not.

Comment: Can you give a link for that question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232336/3969433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error was in my vertex data, because when I re-wrote my vertex data, the problem gone.